# Do I need docker to run Kubernetes in production?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

As docker means many things :

- the docker images
- and the tools to run the images (docker engine)

I am confused and it's not clear for me:
Are the "docker engine" mandatory to use Kubernetes to run docker images.

If not, is it still recommended to run kubernetes with the docker engine ?

I found in kubernetes doc that rkt would be the alternative to avoid dockerd, but does it hold as a sound configuration for production cluster ?

Moreover since the licensing change in docker,
What are people using in production environment:
RHEL + docker EE + Kubernetes ?

EDIT: clarify question to target production environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Kubernetes often comes bundled up with the things necessary to run containers, but it itself is a container orchestration system. So if you're going to need whatever base container engine you need to run the kind of containers you want (Docker or otherwise).

I would personally recommend Docker unless you're using some other container solution simply because it is currently the most fleshed out, with the most support.

Answer (score 2):

The docker engine is no longer mandatory, merely the default. The Kubernetes documentation describes how you could alternatively use rkt:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/rkt/

I tend to agree with @Chris, stick with Docker. It's the most widely supported container engine on all platforms.

---

**Additional**

It's worth noting that I experienced some confusion with regard to how the docker engine is packaged for Redhat systems. Prior Docker's recent licensing change there were unbelievably 3 different RPM packages to choose from:

- *docker*          (Stable docker version to support Openshift)
- *docker-latest*   (Most up to date version of docker supported by Redhat)
- *docker-engine*   (RPM sourced from the Docker Inc. repository)

The recent licencing change seems to have introduced yet another new RPM package: "*docker-ce*"..... Madness....

Long story short, just use the "docker-latest" package supported by Redhat. I stopped using the packages from Docker Inc. as it was simpler to let Redhat deal with the backward compatibility problems periodically introduced by new releases of Docker.